Requesting proof check: convergence of $\sum_n a_n$ implies convergence of $\sum_n \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^2}$
I have been working through some problems from Baby Rudin and am wondering if my proof of the following prompt is logically sound.

If $a_n \geq 0$, then prove that the convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_n a_n$ implies the convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_n \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^2}$

Proof:
Since $a_n \geq 0$, it follows that $0 \leq \sqrt{a_n} \leq a_n$.  We then get the convergence of $\sum_n \sqrt{a_n}$ from the comparison test.  Attempting to apply the ratio test to solve the original problem, we try to find
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{\frac{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^2}} \right|
&= \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}{(n+1)^2} \cdot \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{a_n}} \right| \\ 
&= \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}{\sqrt{a_n}} \cdot \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} \right|.
\end{aligned}
$$
From the equality
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} (A_n B_n) 
\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} (A_n) \cdot 
\limsup_{n\to\infty} (B_n), 
$$
we are able to see that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}{\sqrt{a_n}} \cdot \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} \right| 
\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}{\sqrt{a_n}} \right| \cdot \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} \right|. 
$$
Since $\sum_n \sqrt{a_n}$ converges, it is then the case that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}{\sqrt{a_n}} \right| < 1 
$$
via the Ratio Test. We can also see that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} \right| = 1.
$$
Recalling that the product of one and a number less than one will result in a number less than one, we are able to deduce that
$$ 
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}{\sqrt{a_n}} \cdot \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} \right| 
\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{\sqrt{a_{n+1}}}{\sqrt{a_n}} \right| \cdot \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} \right| < 1,
$$
and thus find that $\sum_n \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^2}$ converges when $\sum_n a_n$ converges and $a_n \geq 0$.

If this proof does not hold, where does it fail?

The first line of the proof is wrong, btw. For example $\sqrt{1/4} = 1/2 > 1/4$

I don't follow the argument. If $\sum \sqrt{a_n}<\infty$, then so is $\sum n^{-2}\sqrt {a_n}$.

Wow.  Thank you.  Don’t really know what I was thinking when I just assumed that.

Your proof is repairable I think. You know the sum of $a_n$ converges, so combine the square roots in the fraction you get and pull the resulting square root out of the $\limsup$ to conclude.

As I said in the comment, the inequality $\sqrt{a_n} \le a_n$ is wrong. Since $\sum_n a_n$ converges, we have $a_n \rightarrow 0$. Thus, $0 \le a_n \le 1$ for $n \ge N$, which implies $a_n^2 \le a_n$, or $a_n \le \sqrt{a_n} \ \forall n \ge N$.
Hint: Use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality for the partial sum

 Apply the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality for the partial sum $\sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^2}$, we get $$ \sum_{n = 1}^N \dfrac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^2} \le \sqrt{\sum_{n = 1}^N a_n \cdot \sum_{n = 1}^N \dfrac{1}{n^4}} $$

